# Вопрос по массиву php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица Vote

```
vote
(
id int(4) auto_increment,
teach_id int(3),
teach_ocenka int(1)
)
```

И есть 3 пары выпадающих списоков для голосования за преподавателя. (приложил скрин))
Левый список - преподаватели, выводятся из БД. Правый оценка.
Код левого списка:

```
  <select name="teach1">
    <?
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT teach_fam, teach_name FROM teachers");
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
    do 
    {printf ("<option value='%s'>%s %s</option>",$myrow['id'],$myrow["teach_fam"],$myrow["teach_name"]);}
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    ?>
    </select>
```

Код правого:

```
 <select name="teach1v">
   <option value='1'><?echo $opt_1; ?></option>
   <option value='2'><?echo $opt_2; ?></option>
   <option value='3'><?echo $opt_3; ?></option>
   <option value='4'><?echo $opt_4; ?></option>
   <option value='5'><?echo $opt_5; ?></option>
   </select>
```

Я сделал через 2 переменные. И, так как таких списков 3 пары => переменных 6 ($teach1,$teach2,$teach3, $teach1v,$teach2v,$teach3v)
В обработчике я заношу их следующим образом:

```
$teach1 = $_POST['teach1'];
$teach2 = $_POST['teach2'];
$teach3 = $_POST['teach3'];
$teach1v = $_POST['teach1v'];
$teach2v = $_POST['teach2v'];
$teach3v = $_POST['teach3v'];

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach1','$teach1v')");
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach2','$teach2v')");
$result3 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach3','$teach3v')");
```

Там еще идут всякие другие вещи, типа если одинаковые значения и тд. Их я опустил.
Вопрос. Можно ли сделать так, и чтобы после нажатия кнопки "Добавить" все шло через массив (например **teach_vote[id_препода][оценка]** и заносилось в БД. Примерный алгоритм в той же картинке в приложении.
PS: Там просто может быть и не 3 препода, а 4 и 5, и N. Версию без массивов я сделал. Но не могу понять как засандалить в массив и записать их в БД.
Алгоритм на изображении. [Прикрепленная картинка ImageHost.kz](http://ImageZone.kz/pictures/77ad1252d21fe087cd8e108a752da1d0.jpg)

Comment: Честно, не понял зачем do..while вместо обычного while? На мой взгляд, это вредная привычка. Да и в sql id не запрашивается, хотя потом используется.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="saveprepod.php">

<p>Препод 1</p>   <select> name="prepod[]">  
    <option value="1">Вася</option>  
    <option value="2">Петя</option>  
    <option value="3">Женя</option>   </select>

<select name="ocenka[]">  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
    <option value="4">4</option>  
    <option value="5">5</option>   </select>

<p>Препод 2</p>

<select name="prepod[]">  
    <option value="4">Люся</option>  
    <option value="5">Катя</option>  
    <option value="6">Лена</option>   </select>

<select name="ocenka[]">  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
    <option value="4">4</option>  
    <option value="5">5</option>   </select>

<input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

в saveprepod.php => $_POST =>

```
Array
(
[prepod] => Array(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 6
)
[ocenka] => Array(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
)
)
```

Comment: я нуб) не увидел своей ошибки:) Посмотрел на Ваш ответ и дошло где я ошибся..
 Можно ли еще вопросик.. Каков будет код, если я хочу сделать все в цикле.
Например для тех же 3 преподов, я так понял алгоритм такой. 
$count=1;
ПОКА $count<= 3; 
Записывать в массивы prepod и ocenka
Как примерно будет выглятеть код?

Comment: А foreach не вариант?

Comment: как вариант:

foreach($_POST['prepod'] as $key => $prepod)
{

   mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('".$prepod."','".$prepody['ocenka'][$key]."')");


}

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо:) Разобрался :)
недооценил возможности foreachh

Comment: благодарность также можно выразить нажав на кнопочку "мне нравится этот комментарий" )

Comment: @oneboy с нулём репутации? Сомнительно.